# conducting hollow sphere in magnetic monopole

Tags: gauss-law, magnetic-monopoles, spherical-harmonics

if a hollow copper sphere(or any conducting hollow sphere) is connected to dc at points diametrical and a magnetic monopole is right at the center of the sphere then will there be any movement of the sphere ?[image: a hollow conducting sphere]